# Gitlab run pipeline job only when previous job ran

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline with a production and a development deployment. In both environments the application should be built with docker. But only when something changed in the according directory.

For example:

- When something changed in the frontend directory the frontend should be build and deployed
- When something changed in the backend directory the backend should be build and deployed

At first I didn't had the `needs:`  keyword. The pipeline always executed the deploy_backend and deploy_frontend even when the build jobs were not executed.

Now I've added the `needs:`  keyword, but Gitlab says `yaml invalid` when there was only a change in one directory. When there is a change in both directories the pipeline works fine. When there for exaple a change in the README.md outside the 2 directories the says `yaml invalid` as well.

Does anyone knows how I can create a pipeline that only runs when there is a change in a specified directory and only runs the according deploy job when the build job has ran?

**gitlab-ci.yml:**

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_frontend:
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - development
    changes:
      - frontend/* 
  script: 
    - cd frontend
    - docker build -t frontend .

build_backend:
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - development
    changes:
      - backend/* 
  script: 
    - cd backend
    - docker build -t backend .

deploy_frontend_dev:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    refs:
      - development
  script:
    - "echo deploy frontend"
  needs: ["build_frontend"]

deploy_backend_dev:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    refs:
      - development
      - pipeline
  script:
      - "echo deploy backend"
  needs: ["build_backend"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that your `deploy` jobs require the previous `build` jobs to actually exist.

However, by using the `only.changes`-rule, they only exist if actually something changed within those directories.

So when only something in the `frontend`-folder changed, the `build_backend`-Job is not generated at all. But the `deploy_backend_dev` job still is and then misses it's dependency.

A quick fix would be to add the `only.changes` configuration also to the deployment-jobs like this:

```
deploy_frontend_dev:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    refs:
      - development
    changes:
      - frontend/* 
  script:
    - "echo deploy frontend"
  needs: ["build_frontend"]

deploy_backend_dev:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    refs:
      - development
      - pipeline
    changes:
      - backend/* 
  script:
      - "echo deploy backend"
  needs: ["build_backend"]
```

This way, both jobs will only be created if the dependent `build` job is created as well and the yaml will not be invalid.

Comment: Thanks, this is a fix. I was hoping to find something more job depending than directory depending. But this will do the job.